# How to skip columns in CSV file when importing into MySQL table using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I've got a CSV file with 11 columns and I have a MySQL table with 9 columns.

The CSV file looks like:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11
```

and the MySQL table looks like:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9
```

I need to map the columns 1-8 of CSV file directly to the first 8 columns of the MySQL table. I then need to skip the next two columns in the CSV file and then map column 11 of CSV file to column 9 of MySQL table.

At the moment I am using the following SQL command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

But the above code maps the first 9 columns of CSV file to the 9 columns in  the MySQL table.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[From Mysql docs:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing)

> You can also discard an input value by
> assigning it to a user variable and
> not assigning the variable to a table
> column:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'  
INTO TABLE t1 (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
```

Comment: FYI: I had to add the `(column1, @dummy, column2...` field statement to the end of my example SQL. Initially I had added it directly after the table name as shown the above example but I kept getting a MySQL error.

Comment: can any one tell me how can i ignore the @dummy

Comment: You need at least `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` to avoid "Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns"

Comment: Also add `IGNORE 1 LINES` if your CSV file has a header row.

Comment: @StevePitchers what about what this suggests http://serverfault.com/questions/96401/how-does-one-list-warnings-from-the-mysqlimport-utility  which is round brackets after `IGNORE 1 LINES` where within the round brackets  all the columns are listed?

Answer (score 5):

**step1.deal with awk.**

```
cat file.txt |awk -F',' '{print $1","$2","$5...}'>new_file.txt
```

**step2.load into mysql.**

```
load data local infile 'new_file' into table t1(...)
```

the method below is simple,but not allowed in lower version of mysql.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'  
INTO TABLE t1 (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
```

Comment: I like the use of awk here in showing the beauty of chaining multiple tools together.

Comment: can any one tell me how can i ignore the @dummy

Comment: Need `-F ','` switch for `awk` command for comma delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

@[deemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2575541/deemi):

The only way to ignore the `@dummy` is by setting the field's Default to `AUTO INCREMENT`.
So you can skip the field and just code like this,

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'  
INTO TABLE t1 (column2, column3, column4, column5);
```

//assumes that the fieldname `column1` is set to `AUTO INCREMENT` by default.

Answer (score -2):

I think there is one more change in the code:

The following SQL command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

-will probably result in an data truncation error.

So it is better to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` instead of `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

SO the code will be:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```