# How do I load multi data files into MySQL with specified fields?

Tags: mysql

I've bunch of txt files like this:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc xxxx dddd eeee yyyy ffff
aaaa bbbb cccc xxxx dddd eeee yyyy ffff
aaaa bbbb cccc xxxx dddd eeee yyyy ffff
```

Now I want to use `LOAD DATA IN FILE` command of MySQL, but how do I apply this with multi files ?

And, I don't need `xxxx` and `yyyy` in these files.

Comment: Just execute `LOAD DATA INFILE` multiple times.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to ignore columns in the file.

Comment: @Barmar, The data file is too many ,like 1000+ files.

Comment: Here is [how to ignore some columns from your source file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2139097/1446005).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple shell command:

```
ls *.txt | awk '{printf("LOAD DATA INFILE \'%s\' INTO TABLE tablename;\n", $0)}' |
    mysql -u user -p password db_name
```