# How to skip columns empty in CSV file when importing into MySQL table using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, csv

I've got a CSV file with 20 columns and I have a MySQL table with 18 columns.

The CSV file looks like:

```
firstColumnEmptyNoName, secondColumnEmptyNoName, column1, column2, ... column18
```

If delete the **firstColumnEmptyNoName** and **secondColumnEmptyNoName** in CSV file the *LOAD DATA* is worked, Affected rows: 16726.

With the **firstColumnEmptyNoName** and **secondColumnEmptyNoName** in CSV file the *LOAD DATA* is not worked, Affected rows: 0

How to skip columns **firstColumnEmptyNoName** and **secondColumnEmptyNoName** in CSV file when importing into MySQL table using *LOAD DATA INFILE*?

Comment: See [colrm](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/colrm/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip columns in CSV file when importing into MySQL table using LOAD DATA INFILE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139069/how-to-skip-columns-in-csv-file-when-importing-into-mysql-table-using-load-data)

Comment: I use LOAD DATA INFILE ...