# CSV file skip column in import DB

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

This is my csv file:

[image]

I need import this file in DB MySQL with **LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax**.

The problem are the first empty columns (A and B), if don't have deleted the columns in csv file on import in DB MySQL not working, if deleted this columns the import in DB worked.

I look for solution on google but I've only find how to skip rows (and worked) and not skip columns.

Any idea?

Comment: You are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139069/how-to-skip-columns-in-csv-file-when-importing-into-mysql-table-using-load-data

Comment: This not working in my case.