# SQL CSV file - Skipping all columns after a certain column number

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've been having an issue for days now and have hit a brick wall. Firstly, as the title suggests I have been working to import CSV files to a SQL database.

To be more specific, this is done through PHP scripts on the server and through MySQL into the DB.

I currently have around 30 CSV files (this number is projected to increase) which are updated daily, then a cron script is triggered once per day to update the new data. It loads the file through `LOAD DATA INFILE`. All of this works perfectly.

The problem is:
Each CSV file contains a different column count. The column count ranges between 50-56 columns. The data I am storing in this collective database only requires the first 8 columns. I already know how to skip individual columns using @dummy thanks to the following Q&A: [How to skip columns in CSV file when importing into MySQL table using LOAD DATA INFILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139069/how-to-skip-columns-in-csv-file-when-importing-into-mysql-table-using-load-data)

However, as the dummy count will not always be the same due to the different column counts, I was wondering if there was a way to get the data from columns 1-8 then ignore all after regardless of column count?

Comment: I can't test now, but what about just including only the eight columns to populate? `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c7, c8)`

Comment: This actually worked perfectly. Previously, I tried something similar but was generating an 'unknown column count'. Thank you

Comment: Great, accept an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

A rather rough patch up would be to first read the beginning line in php, to count columns by commas. Then knowing the amount, subtract 8 and generate the sql command now knowing how many columns you need to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the eight columns to populate and it will us the first eight from the CSV row:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8)
```