# Stored procedure issue with csv file upload

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have one stored procedure and it is getting error when I'm uploading the csv or text file using stored procedure.

Can you please help me? How can I write the stored procedure and have one auto-increment column?  Please let me know how we will skip unwanted columns using the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_cat_order_report_gen_meor
begin 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\VikasK\\Downloads\\vikas\\FINRACATReportableEquitySecurities_EOD.txt'
INTO TABLE tbl_catreportableeqsymbolmaster
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
SET tbl_catreportableeqsymbolmaster.symbolid =null ;
END 
//
delimiter ;
```

Please let me know.

Comment: generally you can't use `LOAD DATA` inside a procedure. If you need other than this please share some sample data with expected result set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip columns in CSV file when importing into MySQL table using LOAD DATA INFILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139069/how-to-skip-columns-in-csv-file-when-importing-into-mysql-table-using-load-data)

Comment: No its not answer of my question :(

Comment: OK. Then please expand on your question by supplying sample data from the csv file, the target table definition and a note of the columns you do not wish to load.

Comment: I have 4 columns , in first column i used auto increment for first column.
I need to import the data from csv to table using stored procedure>>
>>here i have some data from csv. 
symbol | issueName| listingExchange | testIssueFlag
A | Agilent Technologies Inc.| N | N.

please suggest..

Comment: before creating a sp try without that.

Comment: Without sp its working fine but using sp its not working