# Mysql Load Data - Is There A Way To Ignore first column?

Tags: mysql, csv, bulk-load

I am trying to load a file into mysql table using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. The csv file and destination table are structured as listed below.

**File /data/data.csv**

```
,col1,col2,col3
,2101,val2,val3
```

**Table**

- col0ID = INT autonum
- col1 = INT
- col2 = VARCHAR
- col3 = VARCHAR

When I run the script below I receive the following error:
`Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'col1' at row 1`

I think this is because of the comma prefix at the start of the line. If I remove the comma at the start of the header and row then the import works fine.

Is there a way to instruct mysql to load the data ignoring the first comma in the header and rows? Or, will I have to preformat the file using code (python or C#) beforehand?

**MySQL LOAD DATA snippet**

```sql
load data infile '/data/data.csv'
into table Staging
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by ''
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 LINES
(col1,col2,col3)
set col0ID=null;
```

As suggested in comments, I looked at a similar [question](How to skip columns in CSV file when importing into MySQL table using LOAD DATA INFILE?) and tried using a variable in columns, e.g. (@discard,col1,col2,col3) but still fails with same error. In my scenario the column header is also prefixed by a comma ,   It looks like I might have to preprocess and cleanse the file before import....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip columns in CSV file when importing into MySQL table using LOAD DATA INFILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139069/how-to-skip-columns-in-csv-file-when-importing-into-mysql-table-using-load-data)

Comment: Thanks, tried using (@discard,col1,col2,col3) but still fails with same error. In my scenario the column header is also prefixed by a  comma ,   It looks like I might have to preprocess and cleanse the file before import....

Comment: Thanks!!! It did work, I receive a different error relating to a different row now. Appreciated :) I will remove the question within the next 15mins...

Comment: Please don't delete the question. Instead please answer it yourself saying what you did; That way the  next person can get the benefit of your wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it thanks to suggestion in comments of a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139069/how-to-skip-columns-in-csv-file-when-importing-into-mysql-table-using-load-data).

```sql
load data infile '/data/data.csv'
into table Staging
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by ''
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 LINES
(@discard,col1,col2,col3)
set col0ID=null;
```

Essentially it loads the first empty column denoted by the , (at the start of the line) into a variable called @discard.

This now reads the data of 78 rows before different unrelated error encountered...