# LOAD DATA INFILE - MySQL - Find and Replace (remove) some keywords - before importing

Tags: mysql

I use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and imported a large TXT file, which works great. It imports the data in the `mydata` Mysql table  using the following

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Base.txt' INTO TABLE mydata CHARACTER 
SET
   latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (keywords , fixedprice, quantity, description, condition1, image1url, merchantcategory, leadtime, Manufacturer, Model_Number, AZ_Code, Volts, Watts, ColorTemp, Shape, Life, Base
```

)

****Before** importing the data** is it possible to replace the `stripoutwords` in the  `Keywords` and the `description` column and remove it. So check if `select name from stripoutwords EXISTS in the` Keywords`and the`description `column, If EXISTs then remove those keywords from the import`

The schema for both tables is here:

```
CREATE TABLE `stripoutwords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mydata` (
  `keywords` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `fixedprice` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `condition1` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `image1url` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `merchantcategory` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `leadtime` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Manufacturer` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Model_Number` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AZ_Code` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Volts` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Watts` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ColorTemp` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Shape` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Life` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Base` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to present an example of a few rows of input data and the result you want.

Comment: And, see this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139069/how-to-skip-columns-in-csv-file-when-importing-into-mysql-table-using-load-data and this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pre processs the data with a function

you would write a sql query like this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Base.txt' INTO TABLE mydata CHARACTER SET   latin1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@keywords , fixedprice, quantity, @description, condition1, image1url, merchantcategory, leadtime, Manufacturer, Model_Number, AZ_Code, Volts, Watts, ColorTemp, Shape, Life, Base 
)
SET keywords = Removetext(@keywords),description = Removetext(@description)
```

with a function like

```
CREATE function Removetext (
     texttofilter text
) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE stopwords TEXT DEFAULT "";

    -- declare cursor for employee email
    DEClARE curlist 
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT `name` FROM `stripoutwords`;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN curlist;

    getwordlist: LOOP
        FETCH curlist INTO stopwords;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getwordlist;
        END IF;
        -- build email list
        SET texttofilter = REPLACE (texttofilter,stopwords,"");
    END LOOP getwordlist;
    CLOSE curlist;
RETURN texttofilter;
END
```

Here is an example how the function works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28cf0a3ba53afcffcb12740e8d07b912